# Is there mapbox-gl-draw freestyle draw mode?

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

In addition to the point, polygon drawing, I'd like to add freestyle mode. Are there some guidelines/documentations/examples for doing so?

Comment: i havent seen one, you might want to start by looking at the mapbox (leaflet) version as i believe that support free drawing.